# How do I change file writing, adding, and deleting ownerships in order to stop running sudo grunt?

Tags: permissions, gruntjs, file-permissions, sudo, ownership

When I run `grunt`I receive this error

```
Running "clean:server" (clean) task
Warning: Unable to delete ".tmp" file (EACCES, permission denied '.tmp/concat'). Use --force to continue.

Aborted due to warnings.
```

I think this is a pretty simple ownership change. Just not too sure what to change.

`sudo grunt` is of course, working. And for obvious reasons, I'd rather not run this with `sudo`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The UNIX command "chown" should do this. Typing "man chown" or "chown --help" will bring up the full documentation or it can be seen here: http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?chown 
The general syntax to change the owner from root to yourself would be

```
sudo chown <your username> <filename>
```

You could optionally give yourself permission to do this. chmod is the command that does this.

```
chmod a+rwx <filename>
```

This will give everyone on your system permission to do anything with the file.

see "man chmod" or "chmod --help" for full details

Comment: Hmm. `chmod a+rwz .tmp` is not getting the job done. Is this what you were suggesting? Also, `chmod --help` is an illegal option on Mac.

Comment: if I `chmod -R a+rwx .tmp` I get an `.tmp/concat: Operation not permitted` error

Comment: `sudo chmod a+rwx` should get the job done if it's a permission issue

Comment: upon running some of the initial tasks, `npm` and such. I ran it with sudo, so there were some fundamental modules in my project that needed root permission. Your suggestion was technically right, and you could not have reached this conclusion with the context I gave, so I'll mark it as right. Thank you @john6923 !

Comment: I tried this command, and still no success.

`Warning: Unable to delete ".tmp" file (EACCES, permission denied '.tmp/concat/scripts')`